# npm install working in Travis CI but failng in GitHub Actions

Tags: travis-ci, npm-install, github-actions

We are migrating from `Travis CI` to `GitHub Actions`. In `Travis CI`, we have builds for `node` repositories.

`Travis CI` Configuration:

```
dist: trusty
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 6.10.3
```

With this configuration, In `Travis CI`, `npm install` is working.

`GitHub Actions` Configuration:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.5
        with:
          node-version: '6.10.3'

      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4

      - name: script
        run: |
          npm install
```

But in `GitHub Actions`, I am getting below error

```
29484 verbose correctMkdir /github/home/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
129485 verbose afterAdd /github/home/.npm/bower/1.8.2/package/package.json written
129486 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
129487 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
129488 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
129489 silly install printInstalled
129490 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/npm-604-fb46bda8/registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-3.0.1.tgz'
129490 verbose stack     at Error (native)
129491 verbose cwd /__w/website/website
129492 error Linux 5.4.0-1047-azure
129493 error argv "/__t/node/6.10.3/x64/bin/node" "/__t/node/6.10.3/x64/bin/npm" "i"
129494 error node v6.10.3
129495 error npm  v3.10.10
129496 error path /tmp/npm-604-fb46bda8/registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-3.0.1.tgz
129497 error code ENOENT
129498 error errno -2
129499 error syscall open
129500 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/npm-604-fb46bda8/registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-3.0.1.tgz'
129501 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/npm-604-fb46bda8/registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-3.0.1.tgz'
129501 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
129501 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
129502 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

I have tried below steps, but with no luck.

- npm cache clean -f
- rm node_modules package-lock.json

So far I am thinking of `OS` difference between two CIs. Travis being `Ubuntu 14.04` and GitHub Actions being `Ubuntu 20.04` (I also tried with `18.04`)

**Anyone has faced similar issues? Any ideas for work-around?**

**If any more information is required, do let me know!**

Thanks!

Comment: I have a working GitHub action script for node js. not sure how I can replicate this error from my end.

Comment: @Eric We also have one more `node` repo, but on that repo, `npm install` is working  in G.Actions. But I thinking that for this repo, node and package that is failing `strip-ansi` version is pretty old. that's why its failing in latest `Ubuntu versions`.

Comment: The [setup node action](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#v2) specifies that you should checkout your code before calling the action. Have you tried that?

Comment: @DannyB Interesting! I think I tried that! But just to be sure I triggered one more build with checkout first, still no luck.

Comment: Weird. I can confirm it is working. See [this action YAML](https://github.com/DannyBen/actions-debug/actions/runs/911489292/workflow) and [the successful run](https://github.com/DannyBen/actions-debug/runs/2756845451?check_suite_focus=true) - possibly [issues with the strip-ansi module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232406/npm-not-working-cannot-find-module-strip-ansi)?

Comment: @DannyB ahh! I think you misunderstood a bit! The part that you checked is working for me as well! Its just that `npm install` is failing.

Ref:- https://imgur.com/a/N9mZMyb

`Edit: Just saw your updated comment regarding issues with module. Let me try that.`

Comment: also just saw this post in **Related** section. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096338/unable-to-run-npm-start-or-npm-install-in-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1

this is working for me so far.